# PostGIS installation on CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to install PostgreSQL 14.6 in CentOS 7 environment and install PostGIS extension for GIS DATA test, but there is an issue.

All other dependencies (including CGAL) have been resolved, but when I try to make SFCGAL-1.3.8

```
../CGAL_patches/CGAL/interenal/corefinement/Combinatorial_map_for_corefinement.h:29:10: fatal error: CGAL/Combinatorial_map_constructors.h: No such file or directory

# include <CGAL/Combinatorial_map_constructors.h>

compilation terminated.
```

An error occurs and the process does not proceed.
What could be the problem?

build without problem

Answer (score 0):

I was using spack to install SFCGAL-1.8, and it kept trying to use the most recent version of CGAL (5.5.2 currently) which would give me the same error. I forced it to install and use an older version of CGAL (4.13) which got me past the error and installed SFCGAL with no further issues.

```
spack install sfcgal ^cgal@4.13
```

Judging from the release notes of SFCGAL on Github, I assume that SFCGAL 1.8 only works with CGAL major version 4 or under.